# Is there a way to initialize an array of strings in a struct when you don't know how many elements you will put in the string?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct {
  char someString[];
} SomeStruct;
```

This produces an error since `someString`'s size is not defined when initialized.

I want to make `someString` an array of strings, but I will not know the size of the array at the time of initialization. (The elements that will be in the array will depend on user input later in the program).

Is it possible to initialize this as an array of strings without knowing the size of the array?

Comment: Use a pointer instead.

Comment: Your code snippet shows an array of characters, not an array of Strings.

Comment: For an array of strings, the type inside the `struct` will have to be `char**`

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi as in '*someString'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the C standard talks about this in [7.2.18-26](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbyszek/ipp/c11standard.pdf). What you are describing is known as a flexible array member of a struct. From the standard:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member.

Essentially what it is saying is, if the last member of the struct is an array of undefined size (as might be the case for runtime sizes), then when using the struct, you would allocate the appropriate size of your struct including how large you want the string to be. For example:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct {
    char someString[];
} SomeStruct;
```

has the flexible array member someString. A common way to use this is:

```
SomeStruct *p = malloc(sizeof (SomeStruct) + str_size);
```

Assuming that the call to malloc succeeds, the object pointed to by p behaves, for most purposes, as if p had been declared as:

```
struct {char someString[str_size]; } *p;
```

Read the standard for more detail. The buzzword `flexible array member` will show up a lot of information too. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a structure with flexible array. For example

```
typedef struct SomeStruct 
{
    size_t n; 
    char someString[];
} SomeStruct;
```

where `n` is used to store the number of elements in the array.

Then you can create objects of the structure the following way

```
SomeStruct *s = malloc( sizeof( SomeStruct ) + 10 * sizeof( char[100] ) );
s->n = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a dynamic array (it sounds like this, if you get a compile error for it), you can actually overrun the array, as long as it's at the end of the struct, and as long as you can actually access that memory. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SomeStruct {
  char someString[10];
} SomeStruct;

int main (void)
{
    // Allocate 4x space, so we have room to overrun
    SomeStruct *p = malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct) * 4);

    p->someString[38] = 'a';
    printf("%c\n", p->someString[38]);
}
```

Of course, you still have to actually allocate the space, so it may not be so useful to you depending on your case.